# I have a question about this integral $\int\limits_a^be^{iF(x)}G(x)\text{d}x$.

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

Recently, I read Titchmarsh's writting "The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function" and there is a lemma in chapter 4 as follow:

> Let $F(x)$ satisfy the conditions of the previous lemma, and let $G(x)/F'(x)$ be monotonic, and $|G(x)|\le M$. Then: $$\left|\int_b^a G(x)\cdot e^{iF(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\right|\le\frac{8M}{\sqrt{r}}$$

Where $F(x)$ is a real function, twice differentiable, $F''(x)\geq r>0$ or $F''(x)\le r<0$ and throughout the interval $[a,b]$, and $G(x)$ is a real function. I wonder that if this lemma still holds when $\dfrac{G(x)}{F'(x)}$ is not monotonic.

Comment: Are we given a definition of $G$? As it stands this theorem is loosely stated. Must $G$ be continuous? Or just merely measurable?

Comment: I'm sorry,  $G(x)$ is a real function, I forgot to mention this.

Comment: (that's not enough; I was more asking does Titchmarsh assume $G$ to be continuous? Differentiable? Analytic?? it probably doesn't matter but it might)

Comment: There is no more information about $G(x)$ except that $G(x)$ is a real function.

Comment: I have modified it.

Comment: One (somewhat) more general condition is $G$ bounded variation and the bound then is in terms of the total variation of $G$; for arbitrary bounded $G$ and the bound just in terms of the maximum of $|G|$ the result trivially fails as for $G=e^{-iF}$ bounded by $1$ the integral is $b-a$ which in general is much larger than $1/\sqrt r$